# What does the colon mean in this ARM NEON code

Tags: assembly, arm, simd, neon

I'm refactoring some ARM assembly code, and I found these 2 instructions, but I don't understand what they mean. The load and store operations have a colon after the base address register, and I can't find anything in the docs:

```
vld4.8      {d0-d3}, [r1,:256]!
vst1.8      {q12}, [r0,:128]!
```

Does anybody know where to find a complete documentation of all possible combination of operations and parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an [address alignment qualifier](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/as/ARM_002dNeon_002dAlignment.html):

```
9.4.2.5 NEON Alignment Specifiers

Some NEON load/store instructions allow an optional address alignment
qualifier. The ARM documentation specifies that this is indicated by `@
align'. However GAS already interprets the `@' character as a "line comment"
start, so `: align' is used instead. For example:

             vld1.8 {q0}, [r0, :128]
```

Comment: And then GAS changed everything again for the 64-bit ARM assembler, just because.